# Is it possible for AMD/Nvidia to put limiters on consumer GPUs to prevent them from being used as cryptominer without greatly impacting gamers?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, amd-graphics-card

(Opinions aside)

This would likely be a controversial decision for them to do, but I'm more so wondering if it's even possible because I don't know enough about how it would even work on a **hardware** level. *(not seeking software solutions, licensing terms, etc)*

I know that AMD/Nvidia have limited consumer cards from being capable of doing specific things that are usually only needed in professional cards (Firepro/Quadro cards), so I'm wondering if they plan on doing the same with Crypto mining in the future to hopefully prevent all the price gouging of their consumer cards that are happening now.

Saturation of up to date graphics cards to the gaming community is important for AMD/Nvidia in order to keep game makers making games targeting top tier graphics cards. So pure supply and demand models don't work that well if it prices their target audience out of the market in favor of crypto. Which is why I could see them going this route.

But unlike most Firepro/Quadro specific features, crypto is using algorithms that we use for other things as well, just not to the same degree, so I'd imagine if there was a way to limit crypto, it would be by only impacting it when it reaches a certain threshold.

Comment: Why would they care to? They're selling GPUs faster than they can reasonably make them due to the miners. As far as they're concerned sustained demand is a Good Thing (tm).

Comment: Can they do this, they already have for one segment of the market, which you already pointed out.  Will they do it, impossible for us to predict.

Comment: @Mokubai because what I said in the 3rd paragraph. If gamers get priced out of the high end GPU market and they can't saturate the gaming market, then game makers won't utilize the power or integrate the newer features. Do that for multiple cycles and you start running into problems where game makers are generations behind on the APIs and can't update because gamers can't buy newer cards.

Comment: @Ramhound But for previous features, it would be limits on certain specific texture sizes, cache sizes, precision timing, or floating point. But cryptos use algorithms that are used for several other things as well, so I'm unsure if there is a realistic way of limiting it without affecting a lot of other things. I'm more so trying to figure out what _specifically_ they could do to limit it that wouldn't affect non-miners.

Comment: Why would they care about "gamers" over another crowd, another crowd that's willing to pay over the odds at that? They're getting bags of cash literally *thrown* at them and all the while in the background they'll be preparing for the next generation. At the moment they're just singing "we're in the money..." and reaping the benefits. Gaming is cool and all and we want new shineys, but think of it from a product marketting perspective. "A new market opened up and gave us all their money without us asking, are we going to tell those people to stop?" I know what my answer would be.

Comment: @Corylulu You asked if it was possible.  They already have moved to make Crytocurrent, against the terms, for server farms with their products.  They can put anything on their terms of service.  Just a matter of enforcement

Comment: @Mokubai Opens up the opportunity for them to make cards more specialized for them. Right now, they are losing out on tons of money because a large portion of their customers that want to buy cards for gaming simply can't, and they can't sell to cryptominers who will force the price up to 2-3x retail and at the same time also sell to gamers. If they make a specialized card for crypto, they could sell to both markets.

Comment: @Mokubai Also, it's about sustainability as well. Crypto is a gamble at best and not nearly as good of a long term investment as gaming. They have a ton invested in the gaming market and it's all going to waste if they can't sell their cards to those customers that are willing to buy it.

Comment: They are sold out, so they've made the money they can, and scarcity means that when things come back in stock then they will sell out to the people who've been waiting. How exactly are they loosing out on money? If anything they've made *more* money by not having wasted capacity making cards that no-one is buying.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not talking about terms agreements tho, those are totally unenforceable and more so targeted to data centers, I'm talking specifically about hardware limiters on crypto ming that only affects those hashing algorithms at a certain threshold.

Comment: As for a "gamble" I know several people who claim they've not only made their money back, but so much more. Can a gamer claim that they "made money" by playing games? I seriously doubt it.

Comment: “I'm not talking about terms agreements tho, those are totally unenforceable” - They have not tried to enforce a term like that, to say its unenforceable, is misleading.  They could easily create a blacklist of executables and use their now required control panels to implement it.

Comment: @Mokubai Because they are only making the MSRP of the graphics cards that are selling for 2-3x more. The retailers/resellers are making most of that money. On top of the fact that they can't currently price their products for the two different markets. If they made dedicated crypto boards, they could up the MSRP of those to reflect the demand, while still being able to sell to their gaming market. But this is exactly why I started by saying "Opinions aside".

Comment: “On top of the fact that they can't currently price their products for the two different markets” - They absolutely could.  They haven’t released a product targeted at Cryptocurrency, that was attractive enough, to draw that segment to that product.  Nvidia is already putting pressure to their retailers.  They also are selling their own products in their online store

Comment: @Ramhound That doesn't work at all. People will just use older versions of software or subvert it. A software solution is not at all viable. If you don't know the specific hardware changes they could make, that's fine, but that's all I'm asking for. I appreciate your input, but I'm only interested in hardware solutions for this question.

Comment: @Ramhound You say that they could, but in order to do that, they would either need to limit gaming boards in some way or significantly increase their crypto performance proportional to the increased price or both. Otherwise, it would still be more economical to just buy gaming GPU's and nothing changes. So a hardware limit almost certainly needs to exist if they wanted to go that route because I don't see them easily doubling their crypto hashing performance (to match market demand) while also maintaining comparable power usage (which is also important for miners).

Comment: @Mokubai > "You are looking at this purely from a hurt 'I can't buy my dream card' gamers perspective and not an economic perspective." -
I'm not even in the market for a GPU (I already have a 1080 TI) and don't care one way or the other about crypto for the most part. You just seem to be overly defensive of crypto and arguing about economics (that you don't seem to fully understand) and are ignoring the actual question, which was specifically about GPU hardware, not economics.

Comment: I couldn't care less about cryptocurrencies but an extended period of having a saturated supply chain is going to make any company happy. They can keep developing all the while knowing that their pocket are full and they've found a new market to aim newer and more expensive products at. And if and when the bubble bursts the second hand market becomes golden, or demand simply returns to normal. Either way as a company they have no reason to lock out hobbyists trying to make a buck.

Comment: @Mokubai "a new market to aim newer and more expensive products at" directly means "lock out hobbyists trying to make a buck" if by "hobbyist" you mean gamer, that's specifically what I'm referring to in this question because that's how they'd do that. But there is a reason why Nvidia is being outspokenly upset about retailers selling to crypto miners and not gamers and is telling retailers to prefer gamers. Their long term investment is in gamers and this hurts gamers. I've already went over why it's a problem for both short and long term for them to not split these markets on numerous fronts